# is this the only way to install IIS on windows server 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771209.aspx

so i have to create a role and then run a cmd prompt? really??? what happened to 'turn windows features on or off' console functionality?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to install is using the web platform installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Not command line, but powerful because you usually need to install other things also. Lets you select everything and then install the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Not IIS but you could always install Apache!

Answer (score 0):

I used this.

http://www.clickbegin.com/index.php?/knowledgebase/article/43/how-to-install-iis/

Seem to do the job!